# I want to populate address in android contacts either new or existing contact

Tags: android, location, contacts, street-address

As per my requirement i we long press on any location address and try to add it to either new or existing contact i should be able to display the location address in address fields. I tried below solution but didn't work.  I need to populate address in street, city, zipcode and state fileds.

Tried with Intent and putparceableArrayExtra but didn't work either ways. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to make it work. Actually the putParceableArrayExtra(InsertType, )is working fine. My other application was not handling the new extras passed to it. I was able to implement the parsing in the application and now i can see everything on my contacts.

I will update the post later (i have to find it) with stackoverflow link which helped me using parceablearraylistextra.